# Active becomes [Object Object] in Jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

Refer to http://jade-lang.com/reference/attributes/ example:

```
- var currentUrl = '/about'
a(class={active: currentUrl === '/'} href='/') Home
a(class={active: currentUrl === '/about'} href='/about') About
```

So attempted to set my code like this:

```
li(class={active: category === "A"})
  a(href="a") A
li(class={active: false})
  a(href="b") B
li(class={active: category === "C"})
  a(href='c') C
li(class={active: false})
  a(href="/directory") D
```

Categories, A and C are "dynamic" via editor which user selects for posts. 
B and D has no categories. 
So when it is true, it will set active otherwise not set active.

The problem is that when rendering, it will show:

```
<li class="[object Object]"><a href="a">A</a></li>
```

I do not understand why it shows [object Object].
Help and explanation appreciated.

Comment: What version of jade are you using?

Comment: @BenFortune - jade version 1.4.2

Comment: Support for objects in the class attribute were introduced in `1.8`. Update your Jade version.

Comment: @BenFortune - thanks so much. it worked after updating jade version

Comment: please answer your own question or something like that, so that it's marked as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @BenFortune - Support for objects in the class attribute were introduced in 1.8 Jade version, so all I did is to upgrade to the latest version of Jade and it worked.